# Sum order index

Tags: summation

In the following sum, 
[image]

I encounter an issue whereby m ranges from 1 to 0 - when k = j (which is guaranteed for every p). Is this a sensible sum or do I need to make changes?

The 'j-k' stems from the following sum:[image]
It is a binomial expansion summation representation

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should replace $j-k $ by $j-k+1$.

Comment: Unsure - please see updated post.

Comment: $m $ starts by zero not one in the third Sigma.

Comment: The m=0 term gets eliminated: http://puu.sh/w9d15/919afd9839.png